# Desenhar um polígono livremente usando a fabric.js

Tags: javascript

Estou usando este código para tentar desenhar livremente um polígono: http://jsfiddle.net/e5Xth/3/

```
canvas.on('mouse:move', function (options) {
        if (lines[0] !== null && drawingObject.type == "roof") {
            setStartingPoint(options);
            lines[lineCounter - 1].set({
                x2: x,
                y2: y
            });
            canvas.renderAll();
        }
    });
```

O meu problema é que, quando uso esse código na minha página ele não desenha corretamente. Quando começo a desenhar o polígono as rectas não aparecem no local onde as pedi para desenhar mas sim sempre a partir do campo superior esquerdo. quando clico para obter o polígono ele é desenhado no local correcto.

Comment: Você está usando o código idêntico ao daquele fiddle? Este trecho que você postou aqui não tem parte do ponto inicial, que acontece no mousedown.

Comment: Ana, pode explicar melhor o que quer dizer com "ele não desenha corretamente"? Em que browser tem problemas? O jsFiddle funciona bem para mim...

Comment: Sim, estou usando integralmente deste jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/9VDD6/10/). Umas pequenas diferenças em relação ao primeiro que postei mas acho que não essas que me causem o problema da minha página.
Estou a trabalhar em windows, no chrome.
Quando digo que nao desenha corretamente na página refiro-me á seguinte situação: quando clico no "press to draw" e começo a desenhar as linhas elas nao se desenham a partir do ponto que eu quero. Elas partem todas do canto superior esquerdo.

Comment: A parte ainda mais curiosa é que, quando volto a clicar no "press to draw" para obter o poligono ele aparece-me corretamente no local onde teoricamente deveriam ter sido desenhadas as linhas.

Answer (score 1):

## O funcionamento do script

O script consiste num editor que permite desenhar e trabalhar com formas geométricas. Para isso, é necessário clicar no label "PressTo Draw! And to stop", então clicar em alguns pontos dentro do retângulo de desenho e novamente no label acima.  Os pontos clicados serão fechados em um polígono preenchido com a cor roxa.

<sup>Adicionei a explicação porque pode não ser intuitivo numa primeira vista.</sup>

## O problema

Pelo que entendi, o problema ocorre ao desenhar uma segunda forma, pois esta parece interferir na primeira desenhada. O mesmo ocorreria com as formas subsequentes.

## A causa

A causa são as infames **variáveis globais** (`roofPoints`, `lines` e `lineCounter`).

Como elas não são redefinidas após o desenho de uma das formas, a forma seguinte irá incluir os pontos da forma anterior. (Não analisei todos os impactos que ocorriam).

## A solução

Tomei a liberdade de fazer um [*fork* do fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/utluiz/9VDD6/) e aplicar alguns ajustes bem simples.

O principal ajuste foi reiniciar as variáveis citadas no início do desenho de uma forma. Veja o trecho:

```js
$("#btnRoof").click(function () {
    if (drawingObject.type == "roof") {
        drawingObject.type = "";
        canvas.remove(lines[lineCounter - 1]);
        var roof = makeRoof(roofPoints);
        canvas.add(roof);
        canvas.renderAll();
    } else {
        drawingObject.type = "roof"; // roof type
        roofPoints = [];
        lines = [];
        lineCounter = 0;            
    }
});
```

## Conclusão

Evite ao máximo trabalhar com variáveis globais para não cair neste tipo de problema. Sempre use o escopo mínimo para as variáveis.

Por exemplo, olhe a variável `roof` no fiddle modificado. Ela está declarada localmente, pois não havia necessidade alguma dela ser global.

Eu sei que em algum momento é importante compartilhar as variáveis entre os diversos eventos, mas tente fazer isso encapsulando as variáveis em um objeto que pode ser facilmente reiniciado.

Enfim, minha intenção não é criticar, pois com certeza é possível ajustar o script sem dificuldades. Só que se a ideia for incluir mais funcionalidades e torná-lo mais complexo, o encapsulamento vai fazer uma enorme diferença para não chegar ao ponto onde qualquer manutenção faça ele parar de funcionar.

Comment: Boa tarde, 
peço desculpa mas nao me expressei da melhor forma. O jsfiddle funciona correctamente, mas pegando no código desse jsfiddle e usando na minha página ele não funciona direito quando tento desenhar. Quando clico pela primeira vez no "press to draw" e começo a desenhar as linhas elas nao sao desenhas a partir do ponto que eu as defino. elas começam a "nascer" todas do campo superior esquerdo e ainda não consegui perceber.
este jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9VDD6/10/ assemlha-se totalmente à forma como eu estou a implementar na minha página.

Comment: @Ana Qual browser?

Comment: Chrome-windows. mas sinceramente não experimentei ainda em outro.